# how to traverse an n-dimensional array with stride

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have an indexing issue that I am trying to solve. 
I have a n-dimensional array with known shape.
I would like to traverse the array with a stride (possibly different in each dim).

With fixed dimensions, I would do this with nested for loops (small arrays) and increment by the stride:

```
std::vector<int> shape = {10, 10}; // h,w
int num_dim = shape.size();
std::vector<int> stride = {1,2};

for (int i = 0; i< shape[0]; i+=stride[0]) {
    for (int j = 0; j< shape[1]; j+=stride[1]) {
     //print flattened index (row major)
     printf("index: %d\n",i*shape[0]+j);
    }

}
```

But how would I do this with an n-dimensional array (flattened)?
I.e. something like:

```
std::vector<int> shape = {10, 10}; // h,w
int num_dim = shape.size();
std::vector<int> stride = {1,2};

int shape_size = 1;
for (int i = 0; i< num_dim; ++i) {
shape_size *= shape[i];
}

int ind = 0;
while (ind < shape_size) {
 // somehow incr ind by the correct amount according to stride, and shape
 // or check if the ind is in the stride (less desirable)
}
```

Comment: `i*shape[0]+j*shape[1]+k` (3D), `i*shape[0]+j*shape[1]+k*shape[2]+l` (4D), etc?

Comment: No.  That is getting the index from the i,j,k etc.  I need to figure out how to increment a loop that traverses the the multidimensional array with strides in different dimensions.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood based on the code you provided. I assumed you would add nested loops for each dimension. Did you want a single loop on an already flattened array?

Comment: The array is flattened already. Using a single loop or more is fine as long as it works for N dimensions and takes into account stride for each dim.  N and the shape of the array are known, but set at runtime.  I would like to avoid using recursion also.

Comment: do you want code or just an algo to generate subscripts do?

Comment: I think you should abstract the "dimension access" using an accessor function, first. Then over that you can apply the stride without having to mix the 2 concepts. Cleaner, the invariants gets clearer to see (easier to prove).

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo {
public:
    std::vector<int> shape = { 10, 10 }; // h,w
    std::vector<int> stride = { 1, 2 };
    std::vector<int> d = { 0, 0 };
    bool add_end = false;
    void AddStride(int index) {
        d[index] += stride[index];
        if (d[index] < shape[index]) {
            return;
        } else {
            if (index == 0) {
                add_end = true;
                return;
            }
            d[index] = 0;
            index--;
            AddStride(index);
        }
    }
    bool AddStride() {
        AddStride(d.size() - 1);
    }
};
int main() {
    Foo f;
    while(f.add_end != true) {
        //do something
        f.AddStride();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice try, but i don't think it works, and either way you're assuming the memory layout (e.g. row-major or col-major). Since `d`'s right-most index changes the fastest then i guess it's row-major.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Traverse {
private:
    unsigned m_numDim;
    std::vector<unsigned int> m_vShape;
    std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int> m_mStrides;

public:
    Traverse( const std::vector<unsigned int>& shape, const std::vector<unsigned int>& strides );
    std::vector<unsigned int>& traverse();
}; // Traverse

// ---------------------------------------------------------------
// Traverse()
Traverse::Traverse( const std::vector<unsigned int>& shape, const std::vector<unsigned int>& strides ) {
    if ( shape.empty() || strides.empty() ) {
       return;
    }
    m_vShape = shape;
    m_numDim = m_vShape.size();

    // Here Use The Passed In Vector Of Known Strides To Create Your Map As      
    // An Association For Each Dimension With Its Stride
    for ( unsigned index = 0; index < strides.size(); index++ ) {
        m_mStrides[index+1] = strides[index];
    }         
} // Traverse

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
// traverse()
std::vector<unsigned int>& Traverse::traverse() {
    std::vector<unsigned int> vTemp;

    for ( unsigned index = 0; index < m_numDim; ++index ) {
        // Use Your Map Against Your Stored Shape Vector To Do The Traversing.
    }

    return vTemp; // Or m_vShape;
} // traverse
```

Here m_mStrides is easy to work with knowing that m_mStrides.first = Which Dimension and m_mStrides.second = The Stride in that Dimension.

This is not a complete working class but just an illustration to get you started. I also choose to use unsigned int rather then ints because when dealing with shape's sizes, dimensions and strides negative numbers doesn't make sense, however if you are using existing code that is already preformatted using int would be okay, but I would suggest doing error or bounds checking for negatives.

Comment: Could you fill in the `// Use Your Map Against Your Stored Shape Vector To Do The Traversing.`?  Also, why use a map?  m_mStride = stride[i-1] (0 for i==0) right?

Comment: I was demonstrating an example, I wasn't implementing the work of traversing the vector. It is meant for an illustration to give a starting point. I explained why I chose a map in the answer  If you have a vector with { 4, 6, 9 } for dimensions that = 3, and a stride vector { 3, 5, 4 } the map's key value is offset by one from the index so the keys would be 1,2,3 for each dimension respectively and the values in the map would be 3,5,4 for each stride relative to each dimension. So you have a mapping of Dimensions & Strides  [1,3], [2,5], [3,4]. When you go to traverse your vector you know...

Comment: (continued...) which stride is which dimension. The performance hit should not be that large unless if you have over a million dimensions(keys) & strides(value).

Comment: It is basically a helper or wrapper class that would take in your vector of shapes and your vector of strides. I guess you really don't need the map and you could use the vector of strides directly. I just like the association when you are pairing two concepts into one object.

Comment: Maybe I should of asked: are your strides for each dimension continuously enumerated or are they random values?

Comment: They aren't continuous. The strides they will most likely be the same for all dimensions.... Look at the the 2d loop, they are basically increment values for the different dimensions.

Comment: I see, then in your case a map would not be needed, but having the class as a helper or wrapper that accepts both vectors to do the work can still be a good benefit.